# Booting from Live USB while Ubuntu 15.04 is already installed on the HD, makes next boot not find any OS

Tags: boot, live-usb

I had 15.04 already installed on my machine, and wanted to see something on a live system on USB. So I restarted and booted from my USB and played around on the live system.

After I was done, I restarted, and removed the USB stick. Now I get an error saying no OS is found on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use the `boot-repair` utility. You can boot from the Live USB again and run the following in the terminal (for Ubuntu 14.04 and up):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then press `Recommended Repair`. After it's done, you'll be able to boot your OS again. I have confirmed that this is a permanent fix, and it is safe to book from the Live USB again.